# How to straighten the irregular lines in the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, canny-operator

I have used `deeplab` to detect the road and then the edges of the road, I clearly want to detect the edges of the road, not the lane. I got some irregular lines that I want to straighten. Below I have attached purple and green is the `deeplab` detection using the standard model and black and white is the output of the Canny edge detection.

[image: img]

Comment: You'd better merge the purple and dark brown regions.

Comment: Can't you show the original image ? I bet it binarizes nicely.

Comment: If you follow the white line on the side of the road, the problem will not be solved?

Comment: Your problem is not to straighten the lines, it is to fix the gross segmentation errors.